Pretty print a Kotlin JsonObject
Similar to this question but on JsonObject:
import kotlinx.serialization.json.buildJsonObject
import kotlinx.serialization.json.put

val myJson = buildJsonObject {
  put("a", "b")
  put("c", "d")
}


pritnln(myJson.toString())

This produces a valid JSON, but it is a one-liner which is annoying to read. I would like to pretty print it.
I cannot do:
val prettyJson = Json { // this returns the JsonBuilder
    prettyPrint = true
    // optional: specify indent
    prettyPrintIndent = " "
}

val string = prettyJson.encodeToString(myJson)

I get:

Argument type mismatch: actual type is 'kotlinx. serialization. json.
JsonObject', but 'kotlinx. serialization. SerializationStrategy<T>'
was expected.


Is that a typo? pritnln

This question is similar to: Pretty print a Kotlin Json Serializable. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I cannot reproduce that error message you get using Json { prettyPrint = true }.

This is because you are using the default implementation of encodeToString which expects 2 arguments - the SerializationStrategy and the actual value you want to encode, as hinted by the error message you're getting:

Argument type mismatch: actual type is 'kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject', but 'kotlinx.serialization.SerializationStrategy' was expected.

(The default encodeToString method:)
public final override fun <T> encodeToString(serializer: SerializationStrategy<T>, value: T): String {
    val result = JsonToStringWriter()
    try {
        encodeByWriter(this@Json, result, serializer, value)
        return result.toString()
    } finally {
        result.release()
    }
}

(source code)
You need to explicitly add the encodeToString extension function (i.e. kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString) if you want to use only one argument. The internal implementation is as shown below:
/**
 * Serializes and encodes the given [value] to string using serializer retrieved from the reified type parameter.
 *
 * @throws SerializationException in case of any encoding-specific error
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the encoded input does not comply format's specification
 */
public inline fun <reified T> StringFormat.encodeToString(value: T): String =
    encodeToString(serializersModule.serializer(), value)

(source code)
i.e.:
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString // <-- Add this import if the IDE doesn't suggest it
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

val prettyJson = Json { // this returns the JsonBuilder
    prettyPrint = true
    // optional: specify indent
    prettyPrintIndent = " "
}

val string = prettyJson.encodeToString(myJson)

